# Incomplete response from the auto reply database user in ozeki ng gateway

Tags: sql-server-2008, sms, sms-gateway

I am using the autoreply database user in ozeki ng gateway which is capable of replying automatically by matching the keyword from the incoming message with the script file of the autoreply database user and execute the corresponding query that is related with the keyword.But I am not getting the complete reply in reponse to the incoming message.

I am using the following query

k^data

select '$sender',status,copies,course_name from search where book_name='data mining'

here, data is the keyword which is matched with the incoming message text.
When I am sending the message with the text "data".This above query is executing and giving autoreply with the value of first attribute i.e status but not for copies,course_name....But I want that it should reply with the values of all three attributes....any suggestions ??..

Answer (score 0):

Try select '$sender',status + ' '+ copies+ ' '+course_name from search where book_name='data mining'